# Domain Logic vs. Linq-to-Entites and Expression Trees

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

Lets say there's a simple class, something like:

```
internal sealed class Foo
{
    public Foo(DateTimeOffset start)
    {
        Start = start;
    }

    public DateTimeOffset Start { get; }
}
```

In the core domain, we want a single "definition" of what it means to having a "started" `Foo`. Hence we do something like add a property like `public bool IsStarted => Start < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` to the `Foo` class.

However, `Foo` also happens to represent an "entity" in a database, meaning we expect to be able to retrieve lists of `Foo` using Linq-to-Entities (i.e. Entity Framework).

(I know we may not necessarily be happy with the idea of sharing classes between the core domain and data access layer, but that's beside the point of this question.)

When fetching only those `Foo` that "has started", we could go:

```
var entities = _someDatabaseContext.Foos.Where(foo => foo.Start < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
```

But that would obviously mean duplicating logic, and the "definition" of what it means to be "a started Foo" would be singular no more.

We would rather like to be able to do:

```
var entities = _someDatabaseContext.Foos.Where(foo => foo.IsStarted);
```

This, alas, would not translate with Linq-to-Entities, which as of yet has no notion of the "is started" concept.

The question: What would be a good way to encapsulate the definition of "started" for `Foo`, in a manner the makes it readily available both in the application domain *and* at the level of querying the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an expression to represent the test.  Use this expression with Linq-to-Entities, use the compiled delegate for execution.

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> FooIsStartedPredicateExpression = foo => foo.Start < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
Func<Foo, bool> FooIsStartedPredicateDelegate = FooIsStartedPredicateExpression.Compile();

...

Foo someFooVar = ...;
var isStarted = FooIsStartedPredicateDelegate(someFooVar);
var foos = _someDatabaseContext.Foos.Where(FooIsStartedPredicateExpression);
```

Comment: I still think it poses a challenge to the code structure clean, but as a general concept, I agree that this might be the best, simple compromised solution in practice at the moment. If the expression needs input (which was not part of the Q, so that's fine) - like if the `DateTimeOffset` value is a parameter - it's seems a pity that the "domain logic version" needs constant re-compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for such task:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Define your proeprty:

```cs
internal sealed class Foo
{
    public Foo(DateTimeOffset start)
    {
        Start = start;
    }

    public DateTimeOffset Start { get; }

    [Expandable(name(IsStartedImpl))]
    public bool IsStarted { get; } = Start < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    private static Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> IsStartedImpl()
        => foo => foo.Start < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
}
```

Then you can use this property as filter:

```cs
var entities = _someDatabaseContext.Foos.Where(foo => foo.IsStarted);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think LINKQKit is a very interesting product. It may well be a solution for some scenarios and unrestricted contexts.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try carrying started logic as a predicate and call it from both IsStarted public interface and pass it to the Linq code?

```
internal sealed class Foo
{
   public Foo(DateTimeOffset start)
   {
      Start = start;
   }

   public DateTimeOffset Start { get; }

   public bool IsStarted()
   {
      return _startedPredicate(this);
   }

   private readonly Func<Foo, bool> _startedPredicate = 
                     foo => foo.Start < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
}
```

And when using Linq
`var entities = _someDatabaseContext.Foos.Where(_startedPredicate);`

Depending on where you are accessing the DB the predicate may need to be accessible outside Foo.

Comment: I don't know for sure why your answer was down-voted, but I can guess. Let me first say that I think it's a pity that people do that (down-vote) without bothering to explain why. Now, I guess that the reason for the down-vote is that you disregard of the fact we're dealing with "expression trees", not pure Lambdas. It wasn't explicitly mentioned in the Q, but this is implied by the reference to EF. Your solution would result in an in-memory evaluation if using the `_startedPredicate` as is with Linq-to-Entities.